# If I click, I want to move the box

Tags: javascript, css

It's a simple question. If I click the box ,
I want to move 200px to the left. but it's hard to me Please help me!
where's the problem?

```
<style>
  .box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .playing {
    transform: translate(200px);
  }
</style>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box"></div>
<script>
const move = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
move.addEventListener("click", _move);

  function _move(e) {
    move.classList.add("playing");
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a single element, so you have to attach the event listener to every element in the collection.

```js
const move = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

[...move].forEach(m => m.addEventListener("click", _move));

function _move() {
  this.classList.add("playing");
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.playing {
  transform: translate(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName returns array so you need to give index

```js
var move = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
move[0].addEventListener("click", _move);

function _move(e) {
  move[0].classList.add("playing");
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.playing {
  transform: translate(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: @Webbanditten by mistake added :P

Answer (score 1):

Your css property for moving it to the left isn't right.
It should be

```
.playing {
transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

Comment: If you mention only one value then it'll be taken as translateX.
 For example, `translate(2)` is equivalent to `translate(2, 0)`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Answer (score 0):

You can also use that. instead of using **document.getElementsByClassName**, use **document.querySelector**

```js
const move = document.querySelector(".box");
move.addEventListener("click", _move);
function _move(e) {
  move.classList.add("playing");
}
```

```css
  .box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  .playing {
    transform: translate(200px);
  }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this question is already solved but i was just experimenting if any one wants to move the **box** continuously by clicking on the box then this code will be helpful.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <script>
  let offset = 0;  
  const move = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

  move.addEventListener("click", _move);

    function _move(e) {
      offset += 200;
      move.style.left = offset + 'px';

    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button-one').click(function(){
    $('#box-one').css("transform","translate(200px,0)");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button-two').click(function(){
    $('#box-two').css("transform","translate(250px,0)");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button-three').click(function(){
    $('#box-one, #box-two').css("transform","translate(0px,0)");
  });
});
```

```css
#box-one,
#box-two
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#box-two
{
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

#button-three
{
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}

body
{
  background-color: #E1E7E8;
}
```

```html
<h2>Translation on click by using jQuery</h2>
<div id="box-one"></div>
<button id="button-one">translate</button>
<hr/>
<h2>Smooth translation on click by using jQuery</h2>
<div id="box-two"></div>
<button id="button-two">translate</button>
<br/>
<button id="button-three">reset</button>
```